# not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong with my return

Tags: c

first, note this is part of a larger system and this is just isolating the one section which is why pointers are being used.
I'm assuming it's something wrong with my return for powerArgs that I'm trying to print. though I'm not entirely sure what is wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
double* powerArgs(int*, int*);
int main() 
{
 int parmA, parmB;
 int parma, parmb; 
 printf("Enter 2 integers ");
 scanf("%d %d", &parmA, &parmB);
printf("%d raised to the %d power is ",parmA,parmB);
printf("%.0lf \n", *powerArgs(&parmA, &parmB));
}
double* powerArgs(int*a, int*b)
{
    int T=*a;
    int L=*b;
    int t;
    t=pow(T,L);
    return t;
    
}
```

after running I'm left with an error that reads
warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
and
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
which is not the desired print.
I think it's the argument type that the returns though I could be very wrong.

Comment: `double* powerArgs` should probably have dropped the asterisk.

Comment: hint: you return int variable and you return type is double *.  pow return double , so don't need asterisk in return type.

Comment: you have to return double not int :)
hint : cast to double

Comment: thank you comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type you specified for your function `powerArgs` is a pointer to a double. However, what you actually returned is an integer `int t`.

You should probably declare t as a pointer to a double: `double *t;`

Then, it may be necessary to allocate space for it on the heap with `malloc` or something similar, so that the pointer to t is still valid outside of your `powerArgs` function.

Finally, set the value pointed to by to be the result of pow. `*t = pow(T, L)`

Answer (score 0):

comments solved this one quickly so I never to remove the pointer for double and powerArg and rewrite int t; to double t; .